# Relation between choice principles

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

What is the relation between the following two principles?

$$ AC(X): \quad \text{ for every } \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\} \text { there is a choice function} $$

$$ AC_{|X|}(X): \quad \text{ for every } \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\} \text { s.t. } |\mathcal{F}|=|X|  \text{ there is a choice function} $$

Obviously the former implies the latter. The intuition that makes plausible an equivalence between the two principles is that, since every set $F\in\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $X$, the number of different choices cannot be too large...in particular we cannot make more than $|X|$ different choices (hence if the family is larger then we must necessarily choose the same element from different sets). Needless to say, I tried to prove it for a while but without much luck. Of course I am not assuming $X$ to be well-orderable (otherwise that would be easy). In my specific context I have $X=\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, but I am curious to know what is the answer for a general $X$.

Comment: Unintuitive for me. There are *many* $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ with $|\mathcal{F}|>|X|$.

Comment: The standard notation would be $\mathsf{AC}(X)$ and $\mathsf{AC}_{|X|}(X)$. I hope you can see why it is streets ahead of the notation used for the second principle.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, but if $|\mathcal{F}|>|X|$ there will be many $F\in\mathcal{F}$ that will be assigned to the same point. I mean, that's the idea, I am not claiming that this can actually be translated into a proof, nor that the two principles are actually equivalent. I will be equally happy if I could have a proof that the former principle is strictly stronger.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I just took two symbols that looked reasonable to me. The notation you suggest is certainly clearer, I'll edit the question

Comment: $AC(X)$ is equivalent to "$X$ can be well-ordered." Does $AC_{|\mathbb R|}(\mathbb R)$ imply that $\mathbb R$ can be well-ordered?